# Undefined index: menu in admin_menu_admin_menu_output_alter() (line 612 of /var/www/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.module)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

This is the error found in admin area:

- Notice: Undefined index: menu in admin_menu_admin_menu_output_alter()
  (line 612 of
  /var/www/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.module).
- Warning:Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
  admin_menu_admin_menu_output_alter() (line 612 of
  /var/www/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.module).

**Code is:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_admin_menu_output_alter().
 */
function admin_menu_admin_menu_output_alter(&$content) {
  foreach ($content['menu'] as $key => $link) {
    // Move local tasks on 'admin' into icon menu.
    if ($key == 'admin/tasks' || $key == 'admin/index') {
      $content['icon']['icon'][$key] = $link;
      unset($content['menu'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Foreach is line:612

What is the error in this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function admin_menu_admin_menu_output_alter(&$content) {

    // Check if index menu is defined in $content and is array
    if( !isset($content['menu']) || !is_array($content['menu']) ) 
        return;

    foreach ($content['menu'] as $key => $link) {
        // Move local tasks on 'admin' into icon menu.
        if ($key == 'admin/tasks' || $key == 'admin/index') {
              $content['icon']['icon'][$key] = $link;
              unset($content['menu'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think check is array or not

Comment: This fix the problem!

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, `$content['menu']` seems to be undefined, but it should be an array since you are attempting to use `foreach` on it.  Therefore, you would need to do something like this before using it:

```
$content['menu'] = array('value1', 'value2');
```